# Vue transfers in-line style to the next element after removing DOM element [with snippet]

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs2

I'm having trouble with `v-for` and `styles` on vue, take a look on this example, i have multiples alert errors stored on `data`, when the user clicks on the close button the `li` receive some style to move the card to the left, and then I remove that error with `.filter`, but if the element to be removed is the last but one or before, the style transfers to the next element, making it also disapears.

Steps to reproduce:
- Run the snippet
- Remove the second alert

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data(){
    return {
        errors: [
            'test',
            'blah, blah',
            'hey, this is an error message, be careful'
        ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
      dismiss(index) {
          const errorElement = this.$refs.errorElements[index]
          errorElement.style.height = errorElement.offsetHeight + 'px'

          errorElement.style.transition = 'margin-left .2s ease-in, height .2s ease-in .2s, padding .2s ease-in .2s'
          errorElement.style.marginLeft = '-250px'

          setTimeout(() => {
              errorElement.style.height = 0
              errorElement.style.padding = 0
          }, 200)

          setTimeout(() => {
              this.errors = this.errors.filter((error, i) => {
                  return i != index
              })
          }, 600)
          // .2s of margin-left
          // .2s of delay to height and padding
          // .2s of height and padding
      }
  } 
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, #app {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.alert-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}

.alert-wrapper ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.alert-wrapper ul li {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  background-color: #e75147;
  color: #Fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 140%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.alert-wrapper ul li .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #Fff;
  transition: .2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .8;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.alert-wrapper ul li .close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="alert-wrapper">
      <ul>
          <li v-for="(error, index) in errors" :key="`alert-${index}`" ref="errorElements">
              <span class="close" title="Fechar mensagem" @click="dismiss(index)">x</span>
              {{ error }}
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably be using Vue's built-in animation support for this but that aside the problem is your `key` attribute. Vue identifies equivalent DOM nodes across updates by using the `key` and because you're using `index` it's pairing up the wrong nodes. When you remove an item the subsequent index values all get shuffled down by 1, which leads to the wrong nodes being paired up and the final node being removed. You need to use a `key` that won't change when other items are removed.

Comment: @skirtle oh god, I created the key based on a random number and that worked, please, provide a answer so I cant mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with I suggest that you have a read about Vue's built-in transitions. That may allow you to avoid manipulating the DOM directly.

However, the main problem here is the `key` attribute.

When the component first renders it will create 3 `<li>` elements with keys of `alert-0`, `alert-1` and `alert-2`. Technically it's a bit more complicated than that because there are VNodes involved but for explanatory purposes I'll stick to just keys and DOM nodes.

When you remove the item with index 1 the following item is shuffled along a place. So the item that was previously at index 2 is now at index 1.

When this updated array is rendered it will create 2 `<li>` nodes, one with a `key` of `alert-0` and the other with `alert-1`. Vue will then pair up the old and new nodes and make the necessary patches to move from one to the other. This is where it all goes wrong. What you want is for Vue to remove the old DOM node `alert-1` but as far as Vue is concerned it still has a node called `alert-1`. From Vue's perspective it is `alert-2` that has disappeared.

So Vue will remove the node `alert-2`, not `alert-1`. It will then update the contents of `alert-1`. The new contents of `alert-1` will be the same as the old contents of `alert-2`. This may make it look as though the `style` has jumped nodes but it hasn't, it's the contents that have moved.

The solution is to use a proper `key` that is tied to the item itself rather than its index. If there isn't a natural choice in your case then you could use some form of random number or incrementing counter to generate suitable ids in the data.